# Do iPhone photos contain any author, copyright or device-name metadata?

Tags: iphone, photos, exif

I'm writing some scripts to organise my photos and I would like to sort out the photos I took myself from the mix of photos that are on my iPhone.

For example, sometimes I get sent photos via AirDrop or messages and they all end up in my photo library.

I can get the Make and Model from the Exif tag, so that helps to some extent, but is not sufficient in all cases.

I have looked around in the Exif and TIFF data, but there is nothing obvious.

Comment: I don't see anything else in the exif data to truly identify specifically which camera. Only potentials I can see would be phone model, GPS location or the actual file name [fitting into a known series]. None of these are even close to being infallible.

Comment: This article https://appletoolbox.com/how-to-view-your-photo-metadata-in-ios-13-and-ipados/ seems to show most of what the camera attaches to a pic. No Author or Copyright data but there is a lot stuff that *might* be useful.

Comment: [Exiftool](https://exiftool.org) will show absolutely everything, which is what I used to form my first comment.